# Filezilla can not connect my new ftp port on centos 6.6

Tags: csf, ftp, centos6.6

I have a webserver running on Centos 6.6. Recently Config Server Security Firewall send me over 150 email about some malicious bots trying to guess my clients ftp users and passwords. I hate bruteforce attacks and i try to change my ftp port from 21 to ****. I configured my purefptd.conf

```
# IP address/port to listen to (default=all IP and port 21).

Bind *** # My New Port Here Without 127.0.0.1
```

Then I allowed in my csf config file new port all TCP_IN, TCP_OUT, UDP_IN, UDP_OUT both for IPv4 and IPv6 and add iptables rules following resources

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport newport -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport newport -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport newport -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport newport -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

After changes I restart pureftpd and csf. Now when I'm trying to connect to my ftp server via Filezilla 3.9.0.6 it gives me this answer.

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (*,*,*,*)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I changed pureftp conf file's passive connection rows as:

```
# Port range for passive connections replies. - for firewalling.

PassivePortRange          50000 51000
```

And allowed it on csf config file like `50000:51000` on

> TCP_IN IPv4 and IPv6.

Now it works fine.